# Cant access RecyclerAdapter from inside PopulateViewHolder

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have this

```
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatList, ChatHolder>(ChatList.class, R.layout.chatlistrow, ChatHolder.class, chatRef) {
            @Override
            public void populateViewHolder(ChatHolder chatViewHolder, final ChatList chatList, final int position) {

                //try catch block to catch events of no posts, it will most likely return a null error, so im catching it, else
                //find its exception and catch it

                String fullName = mAdapter.getRef(position).getKey();
                chatViewHolder.setName(fullName);
```

But the line

```
String fullName = mAdapter.getRef(position).getKey();
```

says that `mAdapter` needs to be declared final. and when I declare it final, it says , `mAdapter` was never initialized.
Solutions, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access yourself. `mAdapter` == `this`.

You can just use `this` or omit it like:

```
String fullName = this.getRef(position).getKey();
```

or

```
String fullName = getRef(position).getKey();
```